# android-toolbox showcase crashing

Tags: android

I'm an android developer. I just imported latest zip for Android toolbox, and tried to run the showcase:
When the app runs I get the following error.  I am on Android 4.03

```
8-02 14:19:25.534: E/AndroidRuntime(32732): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler

08-02 14:19:25.534: E/AndroidRuntime(32732):    at   de.viktorreiser.androidtoolbox.showcase.AndroidToolboxShowcaseActivity.onCreate(AndroidToolboxShowcaseActivity.java:68)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the BugSenseHandler.  It is not needed.